# CSS Preprocessors on an Android Tablet

Tags: android, css, compilation, sass

When I'm out and about I don't always have a laptop with me, but I do always have my Nexus 7. I like to do a bit of work when nothing else is going on, whether it be coding, or documenting, or whatever else.

I'd like to be able to work on my SASS stylesheets on the tablet. Obviously I can code them easily enough, but I haven't yet found a way to process them in situ.

An on-tablet way of doing it would be ideal, but there doesn't seem to be much in the way of Ruby running on Android.

An online version would be better than nothing, but seeing as I have wi-fi only, I don't always have an internet connection.

So the question is: **Is there a way to compile SASS on Android, either on tablet or online?**

If not, could I do this with LESS instead? I assume so because it's js based, but I prefer SASS so this is a *last option* for me.

Many thanks in advance,
Jorj.

Comment: This online tool any use?: http://www.phpsass.com/try/

Comment: If there's a virtual machine for Android, you can run whatever you want.  This looks like one:  http://code.google.com/p/android-pc/

Comment: Thanks for these. I'm going to look into the VM, even if only out of interest. I think the PHPSASS way is what I'm going to do: I'll set up a server on the tablet and run it through that.

Answer (score 2):

Might any of these help? I imagine they'll do when you really, really want to get some work done while out:

- [CSS Convert](http://cssconvert.mgwebsolutions.net/)
- [css2sass](http://css2sass.heroku.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm going down a similar route, by running PHPSASS on a server on the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the terminal app termux, downloaded ruby and installed sass with gem. 
You can get access to the shared storage as described in the termux help section. So it only works if you have your www folder there. 
I am using this server app, and it works.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.php